# Escaping characters to set string to an HTML tag

Tags: php

I want to set a variable to an HTML image tag with a variable source. Here is my function.

```
function convertImageMod($string)
{
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
$string = str_replace("'", "", $string);
$stringlength = strlen($string);
$stringlength -= 3;
$string = substr ($string, 0, $stringlength);
$string = strtolower ($string);
$string = "<img src:\"images/items/" . "$string" . ".png" . "\"></img>" ";
return $string;
}
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in C:\web\functions.php on line 26**

I thought I had properly escaped all of the necessary quotes.
Any idea what I'm getting this error message?

Comment: what is line 26 and the line before that?

Comment: I think this `<img src:` is the error. Should read as `<img src=`

Comment: @Fred That's an HTML problem, it wouldn't cause a PHP error.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I thought it would've. Didn't know it wouldn't cause the error. Now that I had a second look, it's one `"` too many at the end.

Comment: Instead of using "..." . $variable . "...", which is hard to read, you could use "...{$variable}...", which is a more clean code. Using the {} parentheses will allow you even insert arrays in there "{$arr[0]}" and they will read ok. You could avoid using those parentheses, but, as I said, arrays will fail and your variable names could be mixed with actual HTML. Again, this should work: <?php echo "<img src=\"images/items/{$string}.png\" />"; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo there:

```
$string = "<img src:\"images/items/" . "$string" . ".png" . "\"></img>" ";
```

You may fix with this:

```
$string = "<img src=\"images/items/{$string}.png\">";
```

You are not properly escaped `"` double quotes.

**UPD:**

Also, `<img />` tag does not require a closing tag. See [specifications](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp).

Comment: Even easier would be to switch to single quotes so they don't need to be escaped. I never understand why people make it so hard on themselves.

Comment: @Barmar or use double quotes with single string to not complicate things. Excludes concat and more obvious if you ask me.

Comment: Well I for one, learned something tonight. Great one-liner ;-)

Comment: @CORRUPT **Q:** Couldn't it have been shortened even more by doing `string = "<img src='images/items/{$string}.png'>";`?

Comment: @Fred Done in [**Emilio Gort**'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17937538/2269749). I personally prefer my version. In html I'm always use only one type of qoutes: double qoutes. I do not like quote mixins. Things might get a really ugly fast with such approach.

Comment: @CORRUPT I hadn't seen it till now. And I can understand why you would want to use double-quotes, I tend to use those as often as I can, if I can help it. I just thought that by shortening it, some like having shorter code.

Comment: Especially in worst case scenario: PHP-JavaScript-HTML string, or something like that.

Comment: @CORRUPT I have been toying with the idea. Wouldn't doing `echo "<img src=\"images/items/$string.jpg\">";` (minus the braces) work? What I mean is, would it have worked in conjunction with the OP's code, and if not then obviously there is a special reason in using braces `{}`. From the tests I've made with a basic script, it did in fact work.

Comment: @Fred Yes. It is just a precausion habit.

Comment: @CORRUPT Ok, I was just wondering. However, I do like the look of the braces set inside like that.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont use "double quotes" for the variable and inside 'simple quotes', it's much clean and easy to read

```
$string = "<img src='images/items/{$string}.png'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says you have a " too many in the line:

```
$string = "<img src:\"images/items/" . "$string" . ".png" . "\"></img>" ";
```

It should read:

```
 $string = "<img src:\"images/items/" . "$string" . ".png" . "\"></img>";
```

Comment: why do you need to concatenate the `".png"` and `"\"></img>";`. You can put those under one quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

Line 26

```
$string = "<img src:\"images/items/" . "$string" . ".png" . "\"></img>" ";
```

To:

Line 26:

```
$string = "<img src:\"images/items/".$string.".png \"></img>";
```